# Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: google-bigquery

We just started migrating our queries from Legacy to Standard SQL so we are learning on how to process nested data and arrays now.

Basically what we want to do is to retrieve from `ga_sessions` table the following data:

```
visitor id, session id, array of skus
visitor 1, session 1, [sku_0, sku_1, (...), sku_n]
visitor 1, session 2, [skus]
```

To do so we ran this simple query:

```
  WITH
  customers_data AS(
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid fv,
    visitid v,
    ARRAY_AGG((
      SELECT
        prods.productsku
      FROM
        UNNEST(hits.product) prods)) sku
  FROM
    `dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) hits
  WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
    --and (select count(productsku) from unnest(hits.product) where productsku is not null) = 1
  GROUP BY
    fv,
    v
  LIMIT
    100 )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  customers_data
```

But we get this error:

```
Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element
```

The data that comes from the `hits` field looks something like this:

[image]

So when we addded back the `where` clause:

```
and (select count(productsku) from unnest(hits.product) where productsku is not null) = 1
```

It does not give an error but the results have duplicated skus and we also lost the skus inside the bigger arrays.

Is there some mistake in our query preventing the arrays of being unnested?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want something like this:

```
WITH customers_data AS (
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid fv,
    visitid v,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(ARRAY(
      SELECT productsku FROM UNNEST(hits.product))) sku
  FROM
    `dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) hits
  WHERE
    _table_suffix BETWEEN
      FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
      AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
  GROUP BY
    fv,
    v
  LIMIT
    100
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  customers_data;
```

This preserves all of the SKUs through the use of `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG` over an `ARRAY` subquery that extracts the SKUs for each row. If you want to deduplicate all of the SKUs across rows, you can replace

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  customers_data;
```

with:

```
SELECT *
  REPLACE (ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT s FROM UNNEST(sku) AS s) AS sku)
FROM
  customers_data;
```

Edit: For more reading, take a look at [types of expression subqueries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#expression-subqueries) in the documentation. In your case, you needed an `ARRAY` subquery, since the idea was to take an `ARRAY<STRUCT<...>>` in each row and transform it into an `ARRAY` of the field type in order to concatenate the arrays across rows.

`ARRAY_AGG` creates an array from individual elements, whereas `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG` creates an array from the concatenation of arrays. The difference between them is similar to the difference between the array literal constructor `[]` and `ARRAY_CONCAT`, except that the `_AGG` versions are aggregate functions.

As a standalone example, you can try:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64>>[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12)] AS arr UNION ALL
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64>>[(4, 13)] UNION ALL
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64>>[(5, 14), (6, 15)]
)
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(arr)) AS x_array
FROM T;
```

This returns a column `x_array` where the elements in each array are those of the `x` field from each element in `arr`. To concatenate all of the arrays so that there is a single row in the result, use `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG`, e.g.:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64>>[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12)] AS arr UNION ALL
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64>>[(4, 13)] UNION ALL
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64>>[(5, 14), (6, 15)]
)
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(arr))) AS x_array
FROM T;
```

For your other question, `REPLACE` accepts a list of expressions paired with the columns that they are meant to replace. The expression can be something simple such as a literal, or it can be something more complicated such as an `ARRAY` subquery, which is what I used. For example:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y, true AS z UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'bar', false UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'baz', true
)
SELECT * REPLACE(1 - x AS x, CAST(x AS STRING) AS y)
FROM T;
```

This replaces the original `x` and `y` columns that would have been returned from the `SELECT *` with the results of `1 - x` and `CAST(x AS STRING)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Elliott! It worked! Could you please explain us why what we did before was wrong? When we unnest the field `productsku` and then use `array_agg` shouldn't it have worked? Why we need to cast it back to `array`? Also, could you please explain the `select * replace` syntax? I read the documentation about it but couldn't understand how it's working in this query. Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: I started writing a comment but didn't have enough space, so I updated the answer. Feel free to post another question if you'd like more information on a topic. Thanks!

Comment: ooh no I see it! Now I understand what I did wrong. Thanks a lot for the help Elliott!

Comment: Is the ARRAY subquery standard SQL syntax? I can't seem to find other databases that support this apart from BigQuery.

Comment: PostgreSQL supports this as well. Try this, for instance: `select array(select x + 1 from unnest(array[1, 2, 3]) as x) as arr;`. It's been quite a while since we added support in BigQuery, so I can't remember which part of the standard we used as a reference, unfortunately.